# Android: rotate a point around another point (without losing precision)

Tags: java, android, android-canvas

I'm on Android and I'm trying to rotate a point (A) around a center stopping it only when it belong to the line that connect my center to an other point (B) in the space.

[image]

The point coordinates are something like : pointX = 45.123456f , pointY = 21.654321f , and the point B is not moving.

I'm using this code inside a running thread :

```
pointAX = (float) (centerX + ray*Math.cos(SPEED*time));
pointAY = (float) (centerY + ray*Math.sin(SPEED*time));

canvas.drawCircle(pointAX,pointAY, 2, paint);
time++;
```

And the trajectory is really good and the animation smooth enough.
How can I manage to stop the point at the nearest position to the line?
I'm using this code but it' doesn't work:

```
if(pointAY/pointAX == pointBY/pointBX){
    stop();
}
```

Even if a try to round the values using only 3 or 4 decimals the point stops in places that are too far from the line.

Answer (score 0):

Your circle is defined by `x^2 + y^2 = r^2` and your line is `y = k*x + b`.
Find point I(x,y) where the two intersect and for each step calculate the distance from I to A on the next iteration. Once the distance begins to increase, stop.

Checking for x/y will give you quite different precision depending on the step you choose and the radius of the circle.